# CSS ou JQuery - Como deixar toda uma página com pointer-events: none; menos tal elemento

Tags: jquery, css

Quero deixar tudo dentro da div `.divGeral` com `pointer-events: none;` menos a class `.divnaomodificavel`

Esse é meu código, abaixo...

HTML:

```
<div class="divGeral">
        <div class="msgdeerro">Nome de Usúario ou Senha Incorretos!</div>
        <a class="link" href="linkGeral.php"><span class="esqueciSenha">Link Geral</span></a>
        <div class="divsegura">Selecione aqui seu texto: <div class="divnaomodificavel">Texto para copiar!</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divGeral {
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Aguardo ajuda...Pode ser em jquery ou css mas prefiro em css...vlw!

Comment: qual a razão para retirar todos os `pointer-events`? Isso parece-me ser uma solução muito "hacky". se adicionar o seu objetivo podemos guiá-lo para uma solução melhor e mais fiável.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a melhor forma seria dar uma classe para o elemento que você gostaria que mantivesse o pointer events e definisse para que tudo dentro da div mantivesse, exceto aquele. Exemplo assumindo que você poderia colocar a classe `pointer` no seu link:

```
.divGeral > *:not(.pointer) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Ponha a classe `pointer` no seu link:

```
<a class="link pointer" href="linkGeral.php"><span class="esqueciSenha">Link Geral</span></a>
```